# $(AppIdentifierPrefix) is not resolved during build time

Tags: ios, xcode

$(AppIdentifierPrefix) in .entitlements file is not getting replaced with the actual AppIdentifierPrefix. Can someone please shine some light onto this issue?

Comment: What file in the built product are you looking at to confirm this?

Comment: I am looking in the .entitlements file that is included in the .app product.

Answer (score 6):

So here is my understanding of the `YourApp.entitlements` file that gets added to your project when you add capabilities like *iCloud* or *Game Centre* to your application.

(I'd love to see some pointers to official documentation ... if any exists.)

**What are these entitlements files used for?**

So first of all, the `.entitlements` is only in your project for the *build* process. It should *not* end up in the final `.app` product. If it does, select the `.entitlements` file and in the *File Inspector*, clear it's *Target Membership*. (This is how Xcode generated these files actually, without any target membership)

So what is the `.entitlements` file used for then? It is part of the build process where it is taken and processed and put in your final application bundle in two forms:

- First: the contents of the `.entitlements` file is embedded in the `embedded.mobileprovision` file. This is a signed property list with a binary signature on top but if you open it up in a text editor you can see there is a `<key>Entitlements</key>` section that should have the processed entitlements in there.
- Second: there is also a copy of the `.entitlements` file called `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent`. This is essentially the same file as the original `.entitlements` file except that it has been processed.

**What preprocessor values can be used in the .entitlements file**

I don't think the processing of the `.entitlements` file is documented anywhere. There most certainly is a pre-processor running over it, so that things like `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)` are replaced with the actual value. However, this seems to be not the same as the one that is used for the `Info.plist` file.

The `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)` is the same as the *Team Identifier* that you may have configured in your Xcode project. You can find the configured *Team* under your target's *General* settings in the *Identity* section. If team is set to *None* then there is a good change that `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)` won't be set.

> So to finally answer your question: if you look at those two files that I mentioned above, and you still see the `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)` is not correctly substituted, make sure your project has a *Team Identifier* configured.

**How does Xcode know what entitlements file to use for your target?**

In your build settings you can look at the *Code Signing Entitlements* settings to find out what file Xcode uses for each build configuration. Usually *Debug* and *Release* use the same entitlements file but you can change that.

(For example, for Firefox for iOS we have build configurations for *Nightly*, *Aurora*, *Beta* and *Release* builds. These all have different entitlements files. The reason we have different entitlements files is because we could not make the `.entitlements` pre-processor recognize settings like `$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)` - i'd love to hear if there is a way to do that because that will make our build simpler.)

**What tool processes the `.entitlements` files?**

Not entirely sure. But if you look in the build logs, you will see some reference to a `builtin-productPackagingUtility` tool. This seems to be an internal Xcode command, not something actually present as a command line tool. So that is not very useful.

Now you know pretty much everything that I know about `.entitlements` files :-)

(I'd love comments and turn this answer into the definitive guide to entitlements files - i think there is a lot of confusion around them)

Comment: In my testing, using Xcode 8.0, it seems like you can use any of your build setting values to preprocess your `.entitlements` file (just like you can in `Info.plist`)